# R: Identifying rows by group based on value in row above/below

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns: an identifier, and an occurrence of some event. What I'd like to do is identify whether something occurred before something else.

Ex: in the following table, I'd like to produce a column that places a TRUE/FALSE or 1/0 if there is any instance where the ID ordered cake before coffee:

```r
ID<-c(4,4,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,9,9,9)

Order<-c("coffee","cake","coffee","cake","coffee",
"cake","coffee","cake","coffee","coffee","coffee","cake", "cake")

orders<-data.frame(ID, Order)
```

Expected output:

```r
  ID  Order Marker
   4 coffee      0
   4   cake      0
   5 coffee      0
   5   cake      0
   6 coffee      1
   6   cake      1
   6 coffee      1
   7   cake      1
   7 coffee      1
   8 coffee      0
   9 coffee      0
   9   cake      0
   9   cake      0
```

I'm thinking a solution would entail an `ifelse` statement but I'm not sure how to reference the row below or row+1. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option after grouping by 'ID' would be `match` which gets the index of the first match and check if it is equal to 1

```
library(dplyr)
orders %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      mutate(Marker = + (match('cake', Order, nomatch = 0) == 1))
# A tibble: 13 x 3
# Groups:   ID [6]
#      ID Order  Marker
#   <dbl> <fct>   <int>
# 1     4 coffee      0
# 2     4 cake        0
# 3     5 coffee      0
# 4     5 cake        0
# 5     6 coffee      0
# 6     6 cake        0
# 7     6 coffee      0
# 8     7 cake        1
# 9     7 coffee      1
#10     8 coffee      0
#11     9 coffee      0
#12     9 cake        0
#13     9 cake        0
```

Or subset can do a check

```
orders %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(Marker = first(Order) == 'cake')
```

Comment: Both your options worked perfectly but your second option is the one I went with, very elegant solution and simple I'm ashamed I didn't think of approach it this way i.e. identify the first unique value of the set. Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 3):

Group `Order` by `ID`, subset the values that are either `cake` or `coffee`, and check which is the first one among the two.

```
+(ave(Order, ID, FUN = function(x) x[x %in% c("cake", "coffee")][1]) == "cake")
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
```